# Why does p4 flush not update my have list?

Tags: perforce

My p4 client version is P4/NTX64/2018.1/1705517.
I noticed that some files had accidentally been deleted in my workspace. I synced, but even so, the files did not appear.
I then ran the `p4 have` command and saw that it contained the missing files, and so p4 will not include those files in the sync.
Of course I can give the `p4 sync` command with the `-f` flag, but my workspace is rather large, so that would take a long time.
I then ran the `flush` command even with the `-f` flag thinking that it would correct my `have` list to reflect what I actually had on the filesystem of my workspace, but it didn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p4 flush` changes the `have` list to match whatever you tell it to match (if no arguments, then `#head` is the default).  If that's not what your workspace actually contains, then the have list is now out of sync with the workspace, and future `p4 sync` commands will probably skip a bunch of files (exactly like you're seeing now).

The command you want is `p4 clean`, which syncs your workspace to match your have list.  (If you have changes in unopened files, including "new" files that you haven't opened with `p4 add`, this will irrevocably blast them.  Careful!)

If you want to open the files that don't match your have list, use `p4 reconcile` instead.  (You can follow it up with `p4 revert` to discard the changes, or `p4 submit` to keep them permanently.)

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for.